# Javascript: Add object to Existing Array of objects with the same key not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to add `newList` to the `Grouped` Array where the `Grouped` Array name is the same as the `newList` name . Eg to concat the "Dairy and Eggs" objects from `newList`  to the `Grouped` Array . This is demonstrated in the desired output.

What I have tried:

```
const existingCatrgory = Grouped.findIndex(
    item => item.name === 'Spices' || 'Dairy and Eggs' || 'Produce'
);

if (existingCatrgory >= 0) {
    const findShoppingCategory = Grouped.filter(x => x.name === 'Spices' || 'Dairy and Eggs' || 'Produce')
    const merge = findShoppingCategory.map((element) => {
        return {
            ...element,
            data: element.data.concat(newList)
        };
    });
} else {
    return Grouped.concat(newList)
}
```

This is the `newList`:

```
const newList = [{
        data: [{
            value: "whipped cream"
        }, ],
        name: "Dairy and Eggs",
    },
    {
        data: [{
            value: "mushrooms",
        }],
        name: "Produce",
    }
]
```

This is the `Grouped Array`

```
const Grouped = [{
        data: [{
            value: "paprika",
        }, ],
        name: "Spices",
    },
    {
        data: [
            {value: "milk"},
            {value: "Blue cheese"},
        ],
        name: "Dairy and Eggs",
    },
];
```

Desired Output:

```
const Output = [{
    data: [
        { value: "paprika" },],
    name: "Spices",
},
{
    data: [
        { value: "milk" },
        { value: "Blue cheese" },
        { value: "whipped cream" },
    ],
    name: "Dairy and Eggs"
},
{
    data: [
        { value: "mushrooms" }
    ],
    name: "Produce",
}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const Grouped = [{
        data: [{
            value: "paprika",
        }, ],
        name: "Spices"
    },
    {
        data: [
            {value: "milk"},
            {value: "Blue cheese"},
        ],
        name: "Dairy and Eggs"
    },
];

const newList = [{
        data: [{
            value: "whipped cream"
        }, ],
        name: "Dairy and Eggs"
    },
    {
        data: [{
            value: "mushrooms",
        }],
        name: "Produce"
    }
]

const mergedList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Grouped));

newList.forEach(function(item){
  let thisGroup = mergedList.filter(g => g.name == item.name);
  if (thisGroup.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.data.length; i++) {
      thisGroup[0].data.push({"value": item.data[i].value});
    }
  } else {
    mergedList.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(mergedList);
```

Just loop through each of the new items and check if the name already exists, if it does, append the new data.value to the existing data list. If it doesn't exist, create a new entry for the item.

As requested, I've updated the code to include taking a copy of the Grouped array and merging into that instead.  As the Grouped array has a simple structure, I have used JSON to stringify and parse it back into a new array.

Comment: Wow thank you for your answer. are you able to make this return a new array instead of mutating state? Thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: np - I've updated my answer to include taking a copy of the Grouped array and merging with the copy instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that uses findIndex and either creates a new item or adds to existing data.

```
newList.forEach(newItem =>{
    let index = Grouped.findIndex(item => item.name ===newItem.name)
    if(index===-1){
        Grouped.push(newItem)
    }else{
        Grouped[index].data.push(...newItem.data)
    }
})
```